# zend framework without command line

Tags: zend-framework

Is there any way to start a new zend project without using command line? I don't have acess to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create all the folders and files from the ZF tutorial yourself, or use the zip file from here: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor and create a script file (batch file) for the command to create a new project. Execute the script (or batch) through a navigator/explorer.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean, I only have ftp access to the server. Is it possible to exec the command using php?

Comment: He's probably on a shared hosting.

Comment: Why don't you create the project on your local machine and use ftp to copy all files to the server? AFAIK, a new project is a folder structure with some autogenerated files. For using php - I suggest you extend your question and add a php tag.

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Tool is meant to create and manage your project on the development machine. In any case you should have access to a command line there, either being it your own machine or an external one.

If your development machine is seriously only accessible via FTP, switch to develop on your local machine and/or in case automatically sync modifications to the FTP. There are many tools out there to support this kind of development, and it is also mostly build in many IDEs.